# What's the BGP route `active received accepted damped` status meaning?

Tags: bgp, route

when I use `show bgp summary` command in Juniper router:

```
admin@LA-MX-RE0> show bgp summary 

Groups: 20 Peers: 20 Down peers: 3

Table         Tot Paths Act Paths Suppressed   History Damp State   Pending

inet.0              

                1784136    830565         0         0         0         0

inet6.0             

                   7597      7597         0         0         0         0

Peer                    AS     InPkt    OutPkt   OutQ  Flaps Last Up/Dwn State|#Active/Received/Accepted/Damped...

12.18.231.2            2114    154937    147211      0      0 5w4d 11:29:20 Establ

 inet.0: 0/31299/31299/0
```

What's the BGP route `active received accepted damped` status meaning?

is the `active received accepted damped` special to BGP route or just normal route's status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Juniper documentation [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/show-bgp-summary.html) actually words this well.

In summary, that is a multipurpose field used to display information about BGP peer sessions. The field’s contents depend upon whether a session is established and whether it was established on the main routing device or in a routing instance.

If a peer is not established, it will show the state of the peer session e.g Active, Connect, or Idle.

If the session is established, the field shows the number of active, received, accepted, and damped routes that are received from a neighbour (inet.0 and inet.2)